# Serializing objects with circural references

Tags: java, xml, serialization, xml-deserialization

I have got 2 simple classes, class representing a bus stop:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Stop {
    /**
     * lines operating this stop
     */
    public List<Line> lines;
    public String label;

    public Stop(String label, List<Line> lines) {
        this.label = label;
        this.lines = lines;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public List<Line> getLines() {
        return lines;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Stop{" +
                "label='" + label + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and a class symbolizing bus line:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Line {
    public String label;
    public int id;
    public List<Stop> stops;

    public Line(String label, int id, List<Stop> stops) {
        this.label = label;
        this.id = id;
        this.stops = stops;
    }

    public Line(String label, int id) {
        this(label, id, new ArrayList<>());
        System.out.println("used second constructor");
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<Stop> getStops() {
        return stops;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Line{" +
                "label='" + label + '\'' +
                ", id=" + id +
                ", stops=" + stops +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I wan't to serialize these using java.beans.XMLEncoder, then deserialize using XMLDecoder.

In this case (when line holds reference to it's stops and vice versa), deserialization fails. Decoder ignores `Line` constructor with additional `List<Stop> stops` parameter and uses the `Line(String label, int id)` constructor, leaving this message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not add argument to evaluated element
Continuing ...
```

When I completely remove list of operating lines in class `Stop`, deserialization works perfectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Main class:

```
import java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate;
import java.beans.XMLDecoder;
import java.beans.XMLEncoder;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(baos)) {
            encoder.setPersistenceDelegate(Line.class, new DefaultPersistenceDelegate(new String[] {"label", "id", "stops"}));
            encoder.setPersistenceDelegate(Stop.class, new DefaultPersistenceDelegate(new String[] {"label", "lines"}));
            ArrayList<Stop> stops = new ArrayList<>();
            stops.add(new Stop("Porte Maillot", new ArrayList<>()));
            stops.add(new Stop("Auber", new ArrayList<>()));
            Line line = new Line("A", 0, stops);
            stops.get(0).lines.add(line);
            stops.get(1).lines.add(line);
            encoder.writeObject(line);
        }
        System.out.println("xml:");
        System.out.println(baos);
        try (XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()))){
            Line line = (Line) decoder.readObject();
            System.out.printf("line: %s\n", line);
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="15.0.1" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
 <object class="Line" id="Line0">
  <string>A</string>
  <int>0</int>
  <object class="java.util.ArrayList">
   <void method="add">
    <object class="Stop">
     <string>Porte Maillot</string>
     <object class="java.util.ArrayList">
      <void method="add">
       <object idref="Line0"/>
      </void>
     </object>
    </object>
   </void>
   <void method="add">
    <object class="Stop">
     <string>Auber</string>
     <object class="java.util.ArrayList">
      <void method="add">
       <object idref="Line0"/>
      </void>
     </object>
    </object>
   </void>
  </object>
 </object>
</java>

used second constructor
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not add argument to evaluated element
Continuing ...
line: Line{label='A', id=0, stops=[]}
```

Comment: Circular references would lead to circular serialization, e.g. "A contains B contains A contains B ...". To break that you'd need to make one of those references transient or mark them to be ignored by serialization and restore them upon deserialization (e.g. when a line is added to a stop then you also add the stop to the line).

Comment: @Thomas so there is no way to deserialize instances with circular references without keeping one of them transient and synchronizing them later?

Comment: Well, I'm not aware of any tool that does that out-of-the-box for XML serialization (Java's standard binary serialization mechanism should be able to handle it). A serializer that writes text such as XML or JSON would need some help in determining how to handle (and break) cycles.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try binary serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circular references causes circular serialization what XMLDecoder can't handle. Making one of references transient and restoring them upon deserialization would solve the problem, as same as using binary serialization instead of xml one.